# TableModel in Java: how to specify different renderers for different rows?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer, tablecelleditor

I'm making a custom TableModel using`AbstractTableModel`for a project, and I need to figure out a way to have a checkbox show up on some rows, but not others. I have already implemented a getColumn method, but I want to be able to have a checkbox not show up unless a certain condition in another column is reached (for example, if the object represented by a particular row is a lightbulb rather than, say, a toaster, give the user a checkbox to turn the light on or off).

I've tried using getValueAt and passing null or a string instead of a Boolean object in the hopes that maybe Swing wouldn't render the checkbox. And it doesn't, but it also throws a nasty set of ClassCastExceptions for trying to cast a String to a Boolean.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could do something like this?

Comment: See also the approach shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7690614/230513).

Comment: This looks pretty excellent, thanks @trashgod! I'll try this if Jens' solution proves too complex to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Columns in a Swing `JTable` are displayed using cell renderers. You should read [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) in the Java tutorials which has a section that describes how the mechanism works. This is how the core method of a custom cell renderer looks like:

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object color,
                        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                        int row, int column) {
```

The task of this method is to select and prepare a `Component` (by setting desired colors, fonts, images...) for a specific row and column that the framework will use paint on to its `Graphics` context. There is a `DefaultTableCellRenderer` that might do the trick without too much custom code (see the tutorial). Note that this rendering mechanism is an optimization chosen by the Swing developers.

You can also learn a lot about customizing Swing components in [Swing Hacks](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596009076.do). The examples are not especially well-designed code but just show how to make creative use of the Swing API.

Good luck!

Example (see comments):

```
    final JTable orderTable = new JTable(dataModel);
    // All columns with class Boolean are renderered with MyFancyItemRenderer
    orderTable.setDefaultRenderer(Boolean.class, new MyFancyItemRenderer());

    // Setting the cell renderers explicitly for each column
    final TableColumnModel columnModel = orderTable.getColumnModel();

    final TableColumn itemCountColumn = columnModel.getColumn(ITEM_COUNT);
    itemCountColumn.setCellRenderer(new MyFancyItemRenderer());

    // ...

    final TableColumn sumColumn = columnModel.getColumn(SUM);
    sumColumn.setCellRenderer(new MyFancyPriceRenderer());
```

Comment: Alright, this makes sense I think. So I can use this method in my table model to specify what individual cells are going to look like, and I can return, for example, a checkbox or a null component and get what I'm looking for?

Comment: In your custom cell renderer you would would check if the current cell index is the one you want to do something about, i.e. provide a `JCheckBox` as the cells render `Component` or an empty JLabel. I tend to write a install a simple but seperate cell render for each customized column.

A little background: The table model only provides the data and manages modifications of that data (insert, update, delete). It is obviously :-) the "M" in MVC (Model-View-Controller). The JTable and the support classes are the View and Controller (V and C) which determine HOW the data should look like.

Comment: Feel free to ask if you're done with the tutorial - I love Swing :-)

Comment: Ah. So what I really should be doing now then is trying to take my `TableModel` and dump it into an extension of JTable where I can then override the `getTableCellRendererComponent` method and pass it components based on the location in the table. Does that sound right?

As for loving Swing, mad props. I cannot stand it, I'm only using it because I have to for this project haha

Comment: Hi, you rarely need to extend JTable. JTable has a lot of customization options. I'm gonna add a little code example to my answer.