# Change Cell Editor for specific Cells with AbstractTableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, tablecelleditor

I have a written an AbstractTableModel for my JTable in my application. I see from tutorials that I can make the column to have a combobox by getting the column model and then the specific column for example:

```
TableColumn sportColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);
...
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
comboBox.addItem("Snowboarding");
comboBox.addItem("Rowing");
comboBox.addItem("Chasing toddlers");
comboBox.addItem("Speed reading");
comboBox.addItem("Teaching high school");
comboBox.addItem("None");
sportColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));
```

But how do I do this for a specific cell or a row?

Answer (score 3):

The JTable’s default implementation is column-based. The only way to change that behavior, if you want to have row or single-cell based choices, is to create a subclass of `JTable` and override the method `public TableCellEditor getCellEditor(int row, int column)`. Inside your implementation you can use the provided row and column indices to make a different choice. The JTable will always use this method to get the cell editor.

Answer (score 2):

you would need to use, override

1. [prepareEditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045851/jtable-how-prepareeditor-works)
2. [TableCellEditor(required to synchronize editor and renderer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16971334/714968)

Comment: See also [`TableComboBoxByRow`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3256602/230513), whcih iverride's `getCellEditor()`.