# How to add others Comboboxes in the same column

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

I want to add two others Comboboxes in the same column in JTable, first i want to put in first row and second in the second row. How to do that?

Comment: I.m not sure you can add more than one combobox to a single cell. Anyway you have to use custom cell editor.

Comment: Override `prepareEditor()`, as suggested in this [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18736206/230513), as well as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3256602/230513) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11003255/230513).