# JFace TreeViewer: a column with different types of data

Tags: java, jface, treeviewer

I would like to create a tree with a column which contains various data types, such as some cells are date, some cells are number, some cells are SWT color, etc. Then I will apply different cell editors for different types, so there will be date chooser, text area, or color chooser,etc for above cells. Is that possible to do so in TreeViewer or XViewer(from nebula)?

P.S, I find a similiar question for JTable:[Jtable with different types of cells depending on data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970824/jtable-with-different-types-of-cells-depending-on-data-type). That could be solved by TableCellRenderer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `TreeColumnLayout` for the tree layout with `TreeViewerColumn` for each column you can then set up the cell editing support using `TreeViewerColumn.setEditingSupport`. You provide this with a class derived from `EditingSupport`.

`EditingSupport` has a `getCellEditor(Object element)` method to get the cell editor for the column with the particular element value. So you can return different cell editors for different element.