# default table model editable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have two questions about jtable and default table model

```
JTable  table = new JTable();
TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(colNames,rowcount);
table.setModel(model);
```

1. I had comboBox added to column 4 and only column 4 should be editable and rest should be not be editable. How to make only column 4 editable?
2. the rows for the table are coming from ms access table, so if the comboBox is changed, I would like to update it in the ms access table too. How to update the data in ms access table?

Comment: *"I have two questions"*  Those are requirements or specifications, not questions.  If your question is "How do I fulfill the requirements?" I would vote to close as 'too broad'.  With that in mind, what is your (one) question?

Comment: @AndrewThompson is correct; if your question is _How can I learn more about these topics?_ I've outlined an approach below.

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to proceed in several steps:

- Start with [*How to Use Tables*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).
- This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7356518/230513) illustrates [*Using a Combo Box as an Editor*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#combobox).
- This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7920159/230513) shows how to override `setValueAt()`, from which you can update your database using [JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html).
- Once you understand these concepts, consider [`DbUtils`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/apache-commons-dbutils/info).