# How to use check box listener with a dynamic JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor

I am new using Swing, that is why am asking a lot; actually, I am searching a lot about this, but I could not found a good answer. I have to do a dynamic table; it has to be filled with the name of the sheets from an XML file, and there is another column with a check box which will be clicked if the sheet has to be validated.

When I create the table it is empty. After an other action it will be filled with the data.

I need to know how to use the check box listener in this case.

This is the main code, the button open performs the filling.

```
public class CreateScenarioUI extends JFrame {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField textField;
String filePath = null;
String[] sheetNames = null;



/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                CreateScenarioUI frame = new CreateScenarioUI();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public CreateScenarioUI() {


    setTitle("Scenario creation");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 450);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    final MainTable table = new MainTable(contentPane);

    /** Button Open */
    final JButton btnOpen = new JButton("Open");
    btnOpen.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    btnOpen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            performBtnOpen();
        }

        private void performBtnOpen() {
            JFileChooser choose = new JFileChooser();
            choose.addChoosableFileFilter(new ExcelFilter());
            int returnVal = choose.showOpenDialog(null);
            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                textField.setText(choose.getSelectedFile().getName());
            }

            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader();
            System.out.println(choose.getSelectedFile());
            filePath = choose.getSelectedFile().toString();
            sheetNames = fileReader.getSheetNames(choose.getSelectedFile());
            table.getModel().addColumn("Sheet name", sheetNames);
            Boolean[] selectorColumn = new Boolean[sheetNames.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < sheetNames.length; i++) {
                selectorColumn[i] = new Boolean(false);
            }
            table.getModel().addColumn("Selector", selectorColumn);
        }
    });

    btnOpen.setBounds(320, 50, 100, 20);
    contentPane.add(btnOpen);
```

}}

And here is how I create the `MainTable`:

```
public class MainTable extends JFrame implements TableModelListener, ItemListener {

DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();

@Override
public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public MainTable(JPanel contentPane){

    String[] setColumnIdentifiers = {};
    JTable table = new JTable(new Object[][] {}, new Object[] {
            "Sheet name", "Create" });
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

    /** Main Table */
    model = new DefaultTableModel(setColumnIdentifiers, 0) {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            if (columnIndex == 1) {
                return Boolean.class;
            } else {
                return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            boolean editable = true;
            if (column == 0) {
                editable = false;
                /**Object value = getValueAt(row, column);
                if (value instanceof Integer) {
                    editable = ((int)value) != 0;
                }*/
            }
            return editable;
        }
    };
    table.setModel(model);
    table.getModel().addTableModelListener(this);
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
    table.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
    table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
    table.setBounds(40, 100, 380, 190);
    scrollPane.setBounds(40, 100, 380, 190);
    scrollPane.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
    contentPane.add(scrollPane);

}

public DefaultTableModel getModel(){
    return model;
}

@Override
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
    //Object source = event.getItemSelectable();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

}

Any help will be useful, thank you everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [default cell editor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) for an editable column of type `Boolean.class` is a `JCheckBox`. *Only* the editor needs to listen to the checkbox, and *only* while the checkbox is being edited. *After* the editor concludes, examine the `TableModel` for changes. If another component needs to know about such changes, it should register as a `TableModelListener`, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13919878/230513). Related examples may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4528604/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7920159/230513).