# Add JCheckBox by for loop

Tags: java, swing, loops, user-interface

So, I'm writing a java code that get a number of places from a file (int pl), the places are named by their number from 1 to max place number(pl).
So I want to get the available places from those places from user.
I want to create in GUI a list of Chekboxes with their names place 1 place 2

------ place pl

and the user check the available places

```
package dlp;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Run1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public Run1() {
    initComponents();
}

public static void main(String args[])  throws IOException  {
  FileReader fr = new FileReader("Dis.txt");
  ArrayList<Integer> dis = new ArrayList();
  String di=  fr.toString();
  String[] d = di.split(" ");

      for(int i=0; i<d.length;i++){
        dis.add(Integer.parseInt(d[i]));          
      }

 FileReader f2=new FileReader("Pla.txt");
 String s=f2.toString();
 int pl = Integer.parseInt(s);      
}
```

Comment: Dont paste the netbean's code Paste the code where you actally think that some question logic is required

Comment: how to create in GUI a list of Chekboxes with their names place 1 place 2 ------ place pl and the user check the available places

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach might be to use a `JTable`. The default [renderer and editor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) for a model value of type `Boolean.class` is a `JCheckBox`. Examples illustrating single- and multiple-selection are shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7920159/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7920159/230513), respectively.

[image: image1]

Comment: +1, And What is the reason for a icon name with `trash` :| This name doesn't fit with your nicer and simplistic personality at all. :)

Comment: The trashcan is my most important design tool! :-)