# jFileChooser as cell editor in a table

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jfilechooser

I would like to set  up a jFileChooser as an editor of a single cell of a table (not entire columns of that table as various other editors such as comboBox etc will be used). Any suggestion or sample code please? (I have already looked into these samples here [How to use tables by Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection)

Comment: *"Any suggestion or sample code please?"* Any sign of effort please?  [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) I mean *besides* asking random strangers on the internet to do it for you.

Comment: can you check out this question please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041575/using-all-jcombobox-jtextfield-jfilechooser-as-table-editor-overrides-the-re

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [tutorial approach](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#combobox) is correct. See this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3591230/230513) that use an undecorated `JButton` to evoke the actual editor. Instead of `PopupDialog`, you'll use `JFileChooser`.

Addendum: To apply the editor to any cell(s) individually, override `prepareEditor()` for the desired row and column, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7045851/230513).

Comment: Thanks for your tips. Can you also check this question please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041575/using-all-jcombobox-jtextfield-jfilechooser-as-table-editor-overrides-the-re