# Disable update button while inserting in textbox for update

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, keyevent

We are carrying out a "Maintainer" program in the classroom to manage a database using MySQL and Java NetBeans. We are just fine, but we want to know how to create some sort of event to toggle "Update Button" disabled while inserting/modifying info into database via textbox/clicked.

When executing the project, we can modify data directly to the Database at MySQL by writing/modifying into table's selected/clicked text box; after modification is done, we need to press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> so modifications gets written, then we press the <kbd>Modificar</kbd> button to make the update effective.

What we want to know is how we can toggle the <kbd>Modificar</kbd> button unclickable while editing on textbox active. Because if we don't press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> first after modification is done, clicking on <kbd>Update</kbd> button while textbox is active/editying throws an error due to data isn't effective yet.

Here we can edit information by clicking on text box (*red frame), while doing that (while textbox clicked and editing info) we want that "Update Button" gets Disabled/Unclickable (green circle).

[image: Image 1]

So far here is our code to the event, but is not what we want:
(where "btnactualizar" its Update Button and "tabla_cliente" is the table that contains the textbox)

```
    private void tabla_clienteKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                         

    if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
        btnactualizar.setEnabled(true);

    }

}
```

This is the Update Button:

```
private void btnactualizarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              

    String Rut = String.valueOf(tabla_cliente.getValueAt(tabla_cliente.getSelectedRow(), 0));
    String Nombre = String.valueOf(tabla_cliente.getValueAt(tabla_cliente.getSelectedRow(), 1));
    String Apellido = String.valueOf(tabla_cliente.getValueAt(tabla_cliente.getSelectedRow(), 2));
    String Patente = String.valueOf(tabla_cliente.getValueAt(tabla_cliente.getSelectedRow(), 3));

    int conf = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Estas seguro de actualizar? ", "mensaje", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

    if (conf == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {

        exeCliente.actualizar_Cliente(Rut, Nombre, Apellido, Patente);

    }
}
```

This is the Update Method:

```
public void actualizar_Cliente(String run,String nombre, String apellido, String patente)
{        
    try{
        conectar();           
        String SQL = "UPDATE CLIENTE SET Nombre='"+nombre+"', Apellido='"+apellido+"', Patente='"+patente+"' WHERE Rut='"+run+"';";

        sentencia.executeUpdate(SQL);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Datos Actualizados");

        conexion.close();
        sentencia.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error:" +e.getMessage(),"Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

    }        
}
```

Thank you in advance for any answers you can give us.

Answer (score 3):

**In general**, because database access is inherently asynchronous, you should perform data manipulation in the background, typically using [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html). A complete example is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34742409/230513). In your context, disable the button prior to starting the worker thread.

```
button.setEnabled(false);
worker.execute();
```

Enable the button in your implementation of the worker's `done()` method, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11372932/230513).

```
@Override
protected void done() {
    button.setEnabled(true);
}
```

**Addendum**: Looking closer at your particular use case, you can disable the desired button in your implementation of the [`prepareEditor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#prepareEditor-javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor-int-int-) method of `JTable`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11003255/230513).

```
@Override
public Component prepareEditor(TableCellEditor editor, int row, int column) {
    Component c = super.prepareEditor(editor, row, column);
    button.setEnabled(false);
    return c;
}
```

Because `JTable` is a `CellEditorListener`, you can  enable the button in your implementation of the [`editingStopped()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#editingStopped-javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent-) method of `JTable`, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13541516/230513).

```
@override
public void editingStopped(ChangeEvent ce) {
    super.editingStopped(ce);
    button.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! I was looking for information about how to implement "prepareEditor" & "editingStopped" but i just dont understand how. I need to create a Class? Where, in the main Jframe? another class?
Never used "@override" before, sorry to bother you, we are students and your solution is something that we have not learned or seeing yet. 
Im gona try to ask my teacher personally, but i dont think he knows the answer.
Thank you very much on advance

Comment: Our jTables are contained by a jFrame. Maybe i should go to "customize code" on each jTable properties?

Comment: I mean, all examples ive seen, don't look even a bit like our project. We just have a JFrame then all public voids like "show", "insert" are there, then we have 3 "mantainers" for each "client","vehicle" & "register". We have nothing else. We must create a new Package? new Interface?

Comment: I would limit the scope of the GUI builder, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2561540/230513), until you understand more, and study the examples cited to learn how `JTable` works with JDBC.