# JTable enable and disable checkbox by checking one in other column

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, jtable, jcheckbox

I have a JTable with few columns that are painted as checkboxes. What I want to do is to enable/disable checkbox from Column A by checking/unchecking corresponding checkbox in Column B.

I have managed to do it basing on [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798980/jtable-disable-checkbox-in-cell), but I have a problem with newly enabled/disabled checkboxes - they are not refreshing properly. Checkbox which was enabled/disabled last is refreshed only after I click on any other cell in the table.

Problem looks like this ("Ref. structure" column is the one with enabled/disabled checkboxes):

Checkbox not enabled:

[image: Checkbox not enabled]

Checkbox not disabled:

[image: Checkbox not disabled]

This is my JTable code:

```
public class StructuresJTable extends JTable {

public StructuresJTable() {
    super();
}

public StructuresJTable(TableModel dm) {
    super(dm);
}

@Override
public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row,
        int col) {
    Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, col);
    if (col == StructuresTableModel.COMPARISON_REF_STRUCT_COL) {
        c.setEnabled((Boolean) this.dataModel.getValueAt(row,
                StructuresTableModel.COMPARE_COL));
    } else {
        c.setEnabled(true);
    }
    return c;
}

}
```

Do you have any suggestions how to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't looked at your code, but in general with Swing tables, lists and trees, the renderer instance is reused to draw many rows. You need to tell the JTable that its contents has changed, so that it may redraw the relevant rows. Use the model to notify its TableModelListeners that some rows have changed.

Comment: I think that not true, JTable doesn't required repaint(), please see my comment in (@trashgod) post

Comment: Thank you, calling fireTableRowsUpdated(row, row); in my TableModel setValue() method worked.

Comment: -1 for suggesting repaint() -- that's _never_ needed if the model is correctly implemented

Comment: [with important notice about TableModelListener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099098/why-never-change-the-notifier-in-receiving-a-change-event)

Comment: @kleopatra: You are of course correct, I'll remove the suggestion :)

Answer (score 3):

Update: Using `prepareRenderer()` versus implementing `TableCellRenderer` isn't so important as conditioning the model correctly. If the model is correct, the view will follow. You'll need a suitable [model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data), [renderer and editor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender).

- Model: You'll need some data structure to hold the state of each cell. In your implementation of `TableModel`, override `setValueAt()` to condition the desired state of each cell in the model as changes occur.
- Renderer: In your `TableCellRenderer`, override `getTableCellRendererComponent()` to condition the renderer for each cell as specified in the model.
- Editor: The `DefaultCellEditor`, used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4528604/230513) implicitly, should be sufficient.

Comment: [am I wrong or don't undestand](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045851/jtable-how-prepareeditor-works) +1

Comment: @mKorbel: You are correct; the view should reflect the updated model automatically.

Comment: @mKorbel your example repaints the whole table and I didn't want to have field with JTable in my TableModelListener. It works, but I found calling fireTableRowsUpdated(row, row) in TableModel setValue() method more preferable.

Comment: @lasjak: Yes, your implementation of `TableModel` must notify it's listening `JTable` view; a row is the smallest reasonable update.

Comment: @lasjak whaaaaaat, please .... this is about methods implemented in the JTable API not about prepareXxx, `1)` then don't use prepareXxx and to create an mostrum, sure two steps back, `2)` take my comment here as private discusion,