# JTable - multi-type column

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to make a simple properties window using JTable with two columns: Property and Value. I want 'Value' column to be either textedit or checkbox. How to achive it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want different _rows_ in the 'Value' column to be either textedit or checkbox?

Comment: It sounds like you need to override [`prepareEditor()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7045851/230513).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should implement your custom [TableCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html) and [TableCellEditor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellEditor.html).

Then retrieve the TableColumn you need to customize and set your class where you implemented those interfaces.

```
TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(vColIndex);
column.setCellRenderer(new YourCustomCellRenderer());
column.setCellEditor(new YourCustomCellEditor());
```