# Display the next row of a List in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, list, user-interface, jtable

I will try to explain as thorough as possible what I am trying to do, since I am very new at UIs. 
I have a String List, let's call it user_decide, which contains different number of elements.
For example

```
1st Row [192, 495, 393, 399]
2nd Row [384, 493, 945, 559, 485]
```

These number represent the index of some arrays, for example

```
Name[192] = "John", Name[495] = "Mary" 
Surname[192] = "Pap", Surname[495] = "Black"
```

I am trying to make a UI which will have a previous and a next button, as well as a JTable.

The first time, my UI will show

```
1st Column 2nd Column 3rd Column 4th Column 5th Column
Name       John       Mary       etc..
Surname    Pap        Black
```

and when I press Next, it will display the next line:

```
1st Column 2nd Column    3rd Column    4th Column    5th Column 6th Column
Name       Name[384]     Name[493]     Name[945]     etc... 
Surname    Surname[384]  Surname[493]  Surname[945]
```

What I have done so far, is a frame with lots of JTables.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
int cols = 0;
Iterator<String> iterator = user_decide.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext())
    {
        String con = iterator.next();
        con = con.replaceAll("\\s", "").replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "");
        String conv [] = con.split("\\,");
        // It can be used for the "for-statement"
        cols = conv.length;

        List<String> column = new ArrayList<String>();
        // Giving the name of the columns
        for(int i = 0; i < cols + 1; i ++)
        {
            if (i == 0) column.add("");
            else column.add("Column #" + i);    
        }
        // Setting the jtable with a specific number of columns
        String[] column_names = column.toArray(new String[column.size()]);
        tableModel = new DefaultTableModel( 17, cols);
        tableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(column_names);
            JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
            // HERE I AM GOING TO PLACE MY DATA AFTERWARDS
            SetData(table, "Name",0,0);
            SetData(table, "Surname",1,0);


                panel.add(new JScrollPane(table,
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS));
                }
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Results");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setBounds(200, 200, 600, 400);
    frame.add(new JScrollPane(panel,
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS));

    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void SetData(JTable table, Object obj, int row_index, int col_index){
      table.getModel().setValueAt(obj,row_index,col_index);
      }
```

and I had this next button when I was doing trying to do it with a table which would store all the data in a row.

```
JPanel navigation = new JPanel(
new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
JButton next = new JButton("NEXT");
next.addActionListener( new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        int height = table.getRowHeight()*(rows-1);
        JScrollBar bar = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
        bar.setValue( bar.getValue()+height );
        }
} );
```

I would appreciate any help.
Thank you a lot for reading this.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: is there any issue to add a new row on runtime ??? or some issue with tranforming this idea to the code, not sure, clear from your question

Comment: I am sorry, @mKorbel the problem is that I cannot get how I should transform it into code.

Comment: :-) hehehehehehe have to waiting for someone with a new battery in his/her magic globe, have to split to logical blocks and rewrote this question ...

Comment: I will try to:) I was looking for some guidelines of how I should handle it.

Comment: @Dimitra Micha , still not sure, [maybe DYM???](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045851/jtable-how-prepareeditor-works)

Comment: thank you a lot @mKorbel, I was reading a lot of stuff and I did some planning. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class SwitchTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private final String [] name = new String [] {"Alice", "Bob", "John", "Mary"};
    private final String [] surname = new String [] {"Green", "Red", "Brown", "Grey"};

    private final int [][] data = new int [][] {
        new int [] {1, 3, 2},
        new int [] {0, 2, 1, 3},
        new int [] {0, 3},
        new int [] {0, 1, 2, 3}
    };

    private int position = 0;

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return data [position].length + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        switch (rowIndex)
        {
        case 0:
            return columnIndex == 0 ? "Name" : name [data [position][columnIndex - 1]];
        case 1:
            return columnIndex == 0 ? "Surname" : surname [data [position][columnIndex - 1]];
        default:
            throw new Error ();
        }
    }

    public void previous ()
    {
        position -= 1;
        if (position < 0) position = data.length - 1;

        fireTableStructureChanged();
    }

    public void next ()
    {
        position += 1;
        if (position >= data.length) position = 0;

        fireTableStructureChanged();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final SwitchTableModel model = new SwitchTableModel();

        Box toolbar = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        toolbar.add (new JButton (new AbstractAction("Previous") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                model.previous ();
            }
        }));
        toolbar.add (Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        toolbar.add (new JButton (new AbstractAction("Next") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                model.next ();
            }
        }));

        JTable table = new JTable(model);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame ();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add (toolbar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add (
            new JScrollPane(
                table, 
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, 
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED),    
            BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: @mKorbel Note, that pressing `previous` and `next` can change number of columns.

Comment: I am sorry for not accepting your answer sooner, I was just trying to figure out what I should do. Thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: Hello @MikhailVladimirov I was wondering if you help me with a small problem that occurs. Although it seems that I could edit the table - since I click and I could write in each cell individually, nothing is saved in my JTable. If you have any idea how I could do that, I would appreciate any help.

Comment: @DimitraMicha Override method `setValueAt` in table model to save edited values.  This method is called when value was edited.

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov Thank you, you are right, I can now which row and column I change, but still it doesn't hold any data when I press enter:(