# Java: JTable Listener in AbstractTableModel seems to not work

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listeners, abstracttablemodel

I have been reading about the `TableModelListener` (http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/compsci230s1c/lectures/xinfeng/swingmodelview.pdf) for a while now and I am trying to implement a `Listener` for a `JTable` which uses the `AbstractTableModel`.
To explain the different parts of my program my class. My main class `extends JFrame` and `implements TableModelListener` so that is why I have this tableChanged method.

```
@Override
public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {

    if (e.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE)
        System.out.println("It is updated");
    if (e.getType() == TableModelEvent.DELETE)
        System.out.println("It is deleted");
    }
```

My Class SwitchTableModel which `extends AbstractTableModel` - Which is not the constructor -  creates a table which displays some values which are taken from some other arrays. Part of the implementation is here [Display the next row of a List in a JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833607/display-the-next-row-of-a-list-in-a-jtable) .

I use the constructor to call the SwitchTableModel class and create the JTable and the JFrame.

I have also added this row in to get when a value is updated.

```
 public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex); ...
```

The thing that I would like to be able to edit my `JTable` and then save its data, but although it seems that I could edit it, when I write smth for example in a empty field and press enter, it doesn't keep the data. The same happens when I try to change smth in a non-empty field.

Actually, with this code, it continues printing "It is edited" for the whole time that the JFrame stays open.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

***** EDIT *****
My constructor is like this:

```
final SwitchTableModel model = new SwitchTableModel(user_decide);

    JTable table = new JTable(model);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Results");

    table.getModel().addTableModelListener(this); 

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.getContentPane().add (toolbar, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    frame.getContentPane().add (
        new JScrollPane(
        table, 
        JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, 
        JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED),    
        BorderLayout.CENTER);
    //frame.add(checkPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
   frame.pack();
   frame.setVisible(true);
```

}

Comment: Paste the relevant code here. All I can say is that a model which creates a table is wrong. And that getValueAt() has no reson to fire an event: it's not supposed to modify the model, but to get a value from it.

Comment: You would need to register your listener with your table - could you show us where you do that?

Comment: There is no need to invoke fireTableCellUpdated(...) in the getValueAt() method. This is done in the setVAlueAt() method. If your code isn't working the problem is likely your custom TableModel. Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. Although the easier solution is to probably just use the DEfaultTableModel.

Comment: @camickr I wish that I could use the Defaulttablemodel. But, I used this one in order to make everything work for my UI.