# Set Condition for JTable, Java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

I have a jtable with 4 columns where the last column has a combo box,

sample code

```
String[] colNames = {"Name","Email","Department","Status"};
TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(colNames,200);
table.setModel(model);

TableColumn statusCol = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3);
comboBox = new JComboBox();
comboBox.addItem("Approver");
comboBox.addItem("Senior Manager");

statusCol.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));
```

Here the comboBox has 2 options approver and senior manager, I am looking for a way to add condition as, only one senior manager in the table?

Comment: please whats `I am looking for a way to add condition as, only one senior manager in the table?` hmmm see my [question about prepareEditor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045851/jtable-how-prepareeditor-works)

Comment: Please show a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle this within your domain (e.g. add a constraint wherever you maintain your data loaded into the tableModel) and limit the amount of senior managers there. This is business logic, don't implement it in your GUI.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, i did this with bussiness logic but the condition failed when user add new employee and change status at a time, it doesnt work. @Jeroen: I know what you mean, but i thought its a good idea to implement it in a GUI. I would like to try with GUI

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `TableModel` starts out in a consistent state, e.g. no more than one senior manager, the goal is to maintain that invariant when a cell in column three is edited. The hard part is ensuring that listeners to your `TableModel` see any related changes. One approach is to use an object manager, as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11259671/230513) by @Guillaume Polet. The manager fires a `PropertyChangeEvent` to notify the listening `TableModel` when a managed object changes state. The `TableModel`, in turn, notifies any registered `TableModelListener`, such as the `JTable` itself, via `fireTableRowsUpdated()`.