# isCellEditable true for a particular row on checkbox selected when isCellEditable false on checkbox deselected

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox

[image]

I want disable editing Column 1 to Column 9 when Column 0 CheckBox is false and  Checkbox value is true enable editing Column 1 to Column 9 when Column 0....How to do that?

Comment: [see opposite idea](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7045851/714968)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the `isCellEditable` method from the `TableModel`...for example

```
public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    boolean isEditable = false;
    if (columnIndex >= 1 && columnIndex <= 9) {
        Object value = getValueAt(rowIndex, 0);
        if (value instance Boolean) {
           isEditable = !((boolean)value);
        } 
    } else {
        // Other columns...
    }
    return isEditable
}
```

Check out [`TableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) and [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details...

Comment: +1 similair way solved here a few times (edit I'd be to test for boolean, then allowing row index)